# how to make apidocs use packages instead of modules in sphinx-apidoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, api-doc

I'm using docstrings to document python code and sphinx-autodoc to generate apidoc HTMLs. The structure of my packages is as follows: `mainpackage.subpackage.module`, I want apidocs to link to classes from a module as `mainpackage.subpackage.Class` and not `mainpackage.subpackage.module.Class`. My problem comes from the [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) project, for example: I have an `MLClassifierBase` class in `skmultilearn.base.base`, but I'm importing it in `__init__.py` in `skmultilearn.base`, and I want the sphinx-generated apidocs to only use this class as `skmultilearn.base.MLClassifierBase` and not `skmultilearn.base.base.MLClassifierBase` as it does now. Can someone help?

I've already tried:

- set `add_module_names = False` in `conf.py` per [Sphinx apidoc - don't print full path to packages and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276164/sphinx-apidoc-dont-print-full-path-to-packages-and-modules)
- added `"""..  automodule:: base"""` to `skmultilearn/base/__init__.py`
- added `__all__ = ['MLClassifierBase']` to `skmultilearn/base/__init__.py`
- added `.. autoclass:: base.MLClassifierBase` to the class docs

I'm still having a *Bases: skmultilearn.base.base.MLClassifierBase* in every class that derives from `MLClassifierBase`. How do I change this?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/15115514/407651 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/30856279/407651

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution:

```
"""
The :mod:`skmultilearn.base` module implements base
classifier classes for scikit-multilearn's multi-label classification.
"""

from .base import MLClassifierBase
from .problem_transformation import ProblemTransformationBase

__all__ = ["MLClassifierBase", 
           "ProblemTransformationBase"]
```

It produces documentation for `base.ProblemTransformationBase` and not `base.base.ProblemTransformationBase`. You need to have the three elements alltogether in your `__init__.py`:

- the definition of `:mod:` mentioned anywhere
- the imports of classes
- the names of classes in `**all**``