# How can I prevent sphinx from displaying the full path to my class?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I have a project structure like this:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from .module import Class
```

`module.py` contains:

```
class Class:
    pass
```

---

Using `sphinx-apidoc -o package/docs/ package/` and `sphinx-build package/docs/ package/docs/_build`, the documentation for `Class` looks like this:

> *class* package.module.**Class**
>
> Bases: **object**

I'd like to have this output instead:

> *class* package.**Class**
>
> Bases: **object**

Or, even better, without the package name:

> *class* **Class**
>
> Bases: **object**

The user doesn't have to know in which file the class is defined; this information is completely irrelevant, if not confusing. Since `__init__.py` is importing `Class` directly into the package's namespace, users will import this class as `from package import Class`, not as `from package.module import Class`, and I want the docs to reflect that.

Is there a way to have sphinx output the path relative to the package's namespace?

Comment: Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25276164/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/29385564/407651

Comment: @mzjn Both of those ask about removing the module names from the table of contents; but I guess the solution _"write your own apidoc"_ also applies to my question? Is that really the only way? I find it hard to believe that such a commonly used documentation generator has no _"display the useful information instead of the useless information"_ switch.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739816/407651? Seems promising (but I haven't tried it).

Comment: @mzjn Yes, but as far as I can tell, it only supports templates for packages and modules. I may have missed something (I only started learning about sphinx yesterday), but the module template contains this: `{% for item in classes %} {{ item }}`, so I don't think it allows me to customize how classes are rendered.

Comment: AFAICT, sphinx-apidoc recursively looks for Python modules and packages in a "naive" way. If you import something in the package's `__init__.py`, sphinx-apidoc does not recognize that.

Comment: a quick and _UGLY_ solution would be to post-process the generated files by applying regex replacements on a directory tree, something along [these](https://gist.github.com/elFua/29f641b9f0f3f10ddd3ec98b6c4f8d5b) lines

Comment: Did you try changing the class' `__module__` value? E.g. `Class.__module__ = 'package'`. That will have also other side-effects, but in general, I guess it _could_ work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sphinx apidoc - don't print full path to packages and modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276164/sphinx-apidoc-dont-print-full-path-to-packages-and-modules)

Comment: I have seen this done by creating a bunch of "fake" modules for sphinx to document. This gives you tight control over the tree hierarchy in sphinx. 

Keep in mind that sphinx is geared to document python modules to be shared with other python developers, where things like preserving the module hierarchy is rather important. If you deviate from this use-case, it can become difficult to coerce Sphinx into doing what you need.

Answer (score 13):

Try adding `add_module_names = False` in conf.py

Answer (score 5):

While adding `add_module_names = False` (refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66459610/13945013) answer) makes Sphinx render `package.module.Class` as `Class`, it does not help if you wanted to render `package.module.Class` as `package.Class` (i.e., document the class as part of the `package` namespace).

If you want Sphinx to document `package.module.class` as `package.Class`, include the following lines in the `__init__.py` for the package (refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31594545/13945013) answer):

```py
# This lets you use package.module.Class as package.Class in your code.
from .module import Class

# This lets Sphinx know you want to document package.module.Class as package.Class.
__all__ = ['Class']
```